# Awk comparison on files

Tags: awk

I have 2 files:

file1:

```
1,apple  
2,mango  
3,banana  
44,orange
```

file2:

```
1,apple  
22,  
31,xyz  
2,man  
3,banana  
44,oran   
44,orange
```

I need to find the differences from both the files using column 1 and checking column 2. I don't want to use $0 as its printing the lines which of 1st file which are not present in file 2 too.

result output should be printed in file3 as :

```
2,mango,man
```

as of now in other question, I asked and got an answer as:-

```
   { awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}($1 in a) && a[$1]!=$2{print $1,a[$1],$2}{a[$1]=$2}' file1 file2 >> file3 }
```

the issue with this solution is that its printing wrong entries in file 3 due to duplicates present in file 2 (for column 1).
I need to write these duplicates in file 4 and should not be reflected in file3.

Comment: Please edit your post and wrap up your codes in CODE TAGS `{}` button and let us know then.

Comment: What is the output, if there are duplicates in `file1`? If there are more duplicates in `file2` is the first one still always the matching one?

Comment: Hi File 1 will be uniq, file 2 can have multiple duplicates and all uch duplicates needs to be ignored wriiten in file 3 and should be sent to file 4

Comment: Which of the duplicated ids in file2 is to be printed? Always the first one?

Comment: Hi james/Ravinder, I am sorry i have updated the expected result for file 3 in my original question which i think is creating confusion. so i file 3 there won't be any entry for 44 but in file 4 we will have 2 entries 44,oran   
44,orange . In short to your query , we need to print all the duplicates of file 2 in file4.(while ignoring them to written in file 3)

Answer (score 0):

For joining files based on unique records from file 2

`join -t','  <(sort -t',' -k1 file1) <(sort -t',' -n -k1 -u  file2)  | awk -F',' '{if($2!=$3) print}'`

For finding duplicate entry in file2

`awk -F',' 'seen[$1]++`

Demo :

```
$man uniq 
$cat fil*
1,apple  
2,mango  
3,banana  
44,orange
1,apple  
22,  
31,xyz  
2,man  
3,banana  
44,oran   
44,orange
$join -t','  <(sort -t',' -k1 file1) <(sort -t',' -n -k1 -u  file2)  | awk -F',' '{if($2!=$3) print}'
2,mango  ,man  
44,orange,oran   
$

$awk -F',' 'seen[$1]++' file2
44,orange
$
```